# IN MS SQL Server 2008 R2, I want to block insert but allow read operation for multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, sql-server-2008, transactions

I have a table where lot of threads will be operating and it is the most important table of the project, but lot of threads operate on this table.

I have a requirement that it should only insert record if count of its record(where condition is used to get the count) is less than 100. At the same time other queries should be able to read it.
But since it is read by multiple threads it is able to insert more records than 100 as multiple threads can get the same count at the same time and then proceed further to insert record. I had tried using READUNCOMMITTED but it is not helping

I know SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; will work, and I tired it but it slows the read operation too.

Any suggestion of how I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table X with column Id and Active. Do the following - 
1. when a thread starts(or when the transaction starts) hold a lock on the table 
2. if able to get the lock then 
3. check if there is any active column present if yes then loop goto start of transaction.
4. if there is no active column present insert a record and make the record active.
5. When the thread ends or just before completing the transaction make the record inactive.
6.do your desired transaction.